# Highlight all imported modules in python

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python

For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
y = np.abs(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to highlight all the occurrences of `np` and `plt`?

Comment: Not sure if it's doable automatically, but you could use interestingwords plugin to do it manually: https://github.com/lfv89/vim-interestingwords

Comment: I can't answer definitively, but I suspect the answer might be that this is not possible using simple highlighting: Vim's syntax highlighting is based on regular expressions and does not actually parse the code, so it has no way of knowing that the `plt` in `plt.show()` was imported earlier on. You could write some VimScript that searched for imports and then set up highlighting with `:match` or `matchadd()`, but this isn't an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a plugin for this: [impsort.vim](https://github.com/tweekmonster/impsort.vim)

[image]

It originally was only for sorting imports.  Since the imports were being parsed, I threw in highlighting as well.

Not only does it highlight imported modules, it highlights imported classes and functions (if it can figure out their types).